# Getting Started With Writing a File to Excel in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, excel

I have data that I want to have written into a Microsoft Excel File.

I found the following question, but this is using a predefined name where as I want to use a Save Command Window on a menu bar.

[Coding for Excel sheet in Visual Basic 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338443/coding-for-excel-sheet-in-visual-basic-6)

Essentially I have two columns of data, Participant Name & Time In Ring, I want to cycle through an array (I suppose) and have each item on its own line.

Can anyone show me where or how to get started with this?

Comment: Where is the data written initially? Why can't you `import text` into excel via VBA?

Comment: Mostly because I don't know how to start with import text. I'm not trying to have the program open Excel for view but to just save the file. Also this is for VB.NET not VB6

Comment: Apologies, I must've missed the tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to create `csv` document. Use System.IO.StreamWriter class and append comma separated string (e.g 10,abc,10.20) at each line.

You may also use ADO.NET `Oledb provider` and `OfficeInter` Op API.

Comment: @PaulWilliams - Use OleDB or Office interOP.

Comment: Now comes the other part of the question.. How do I get started using File > Save dialogs :/